# multiple ssh keys created, then deleted. now ssh-agent not working. (osx terminal)

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

Attempting to ssh to any server, even ones in my authorized list results in either public key (permission denied) error OR command hangs indefinitely.

When first creating my ssh key, I created multiple keys. Realizing later that I could make do with one, I deleted them, but whenever I tried to ssh *any-server* I kept getting errors.

First attempt to fix: I was able to get it working by terminating ssh processes using ps aux | grep ssh and kill xxxxx and then restarting the shell. However, the problem returned after a reboot and that solution stopped working.

The ssh key I'm using is named something other than id_rsa, but when I attempt to ssh -t git@github.com, for example, it only appears to search for standard ssh key names.

I had created a config file in my .ssh directory that defined identities, but even after deleting it, nothing seems to work.

Help!

Second attempt to fix:

1. `ps aux | grep ssh`
2. kill all processes in the list
3. restart the shell
4. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-ssh-key-name` (*this will fail*)
5. ```
   eval ssh-agent -s
   ```

   #(*this will start the ssh-agent*)
6. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-ssh-key-name` #(*same as line 4, but this time it will successfully add your identity*)

After a reboot though, again I am having problems.

This is my first question on here. Let me know if I should structure things differently/provide more info.

```
result of ssh -vvvT git@github.com verify:
...
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/dharamkhalsa/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I also tried setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0, but still getting errors. I noticed that my bash command line has an ip address rather than my computer name. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: what do you see in the verbose log `ssh -vvvT git@github.com verify`? What is output of `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: ip-1-1-1-1:~ darbarinyc$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.

Comment: So how does the line 4 and 6 fail? What is the error? Can you ssh directly with the key such as  `ssh -Ti ~/.ssh/your-ssh-key-name git@github.com verify`?

Comment: specifying the key prompted for a password, which looked promising, but even after giving the password still failed with the same permission denied (public key) error. I resorted to deleting my ~/.ssh folder and everything ssh related stored in the login section of keychain. Rebooted and generated new keys with a default name. Everything is working now. We'll see if it works tomorrow... :/

Comment: update: haven't had any issues with ssh keys since deleting and recreating with the default name.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an error similar to this when updating `ssh` keys on Mac OS X.  Assuming you are using the built-in `ssh` (or even MacPorts `ssh`), the passphrase is stored in the OSX Keychain, which may have some issue with a new key but stored old passphrase.  Possible workaround:  Open `KeyChain Access`, search for `ssh`, and delete all the "old" ssh stored passphrases;  just make sure you know them or write them down first.   You might also be able to simply enter the new passphrase in the right place too, and then delete the current key from the running `ssh-agent`.  Or just reboot.

I know something along those lines worked for me once, but I didn't write down the exact steps.

Comment: Makes sense. Two weeks after giving up and deleting+recreating my keys (including the keychain records) I've had no issues. Perhaps just deleting the keychain records would've done it. Thanks! :)